# How to read all but one TXT files from a directory in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a directory with several `.txt` files. I want to read all these files into a dataframe, but want to exclude one problematic file. Is there a way I can do this?

The files are named `#100.1-YYYY1HH10MM.txt`, `#101.1-YYYY11HH20MM.txt`, `#102.1-YYYY9HH5MM.txt` etc. You'll note that the file names are prefixed with an incremental number e.g. `#100.1`, `#102.1` etc. If I want to read all these files except say file number `#350.1`, how can I do that? Not sure if I can use regex here.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

filename = '/mnt/directory/*.txt' #Read all TXT files in the folder
filename = '/mnt/directory/#{1[0-4,7-9],[0,2-3][0-9]}.1.txt' #Try regex to filter out one file
```

Answer (score 2):

if your lists are not too big, than using glob and looping can be a simple solution:

```
import glob

dont_want = ['#350.1']
files = []
for x in glob.glob("path/*.txt"):
    for y in dont_want:
        if y not in x: files.append(x)
            
df = spark.read.csv(mylist)
```